# How to run cron jobs according to user's timezone in nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cron

I am using cron jobs to reset a particular field back to zero let's call it a streak I am trying to reset current streak of a user. so for that I am running a cron job at 11:59 to reset the data if user doesn't perform a particular task,But it's running according to UTC time. I want it to run according to users timezone who is using the application. Is it possible to run it according to different timezone or anyone could suggest any other way to do so.

Comment: I would get the UTC time of midnight of all timezones. Then create a cron to perform the task for all users for each timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the time with a lib like http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/.

```
var a = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");
```

or

You should try CronJob npm package

```
  new CronJob(
      targetTime,
      async function () {

        await donsomething
      },
      null,
      true,
      time_zone
    );
```